# Change password Postgresql user using Chef recipe

Tags: postgresql, chef-infra, devops, chef-recipe, cookbook

I need to set the password of my user `postgres` during my POSTGRES installation cookbook on a CentOS 7 node.

From command line I execute the command

```
sudo passwd postgres
```

and the system ask me the new password and then to retype the password.

[image]

How may I "translate" this issue in a Chef recipe? Any example or documentation  somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

A correct way for setting a user password from non-interactively is to use `chpasswd` instead of `password`.

```
echo "postgres:CorrectHorseBatteryStaple" | sudo chpasswd
```

But actually setting password for postgres user on the server is not recommended. This is a system user - it should not be possible to login as postgres OS-level user with a password. You should use `sudo su - postgres` or `sudo -u postgres` instead.

Are you sure that the actual requirement is not about the "postgres" database superuser?

I don't know chef, so no ready-made recipe for you.

Comment: I'm following this guide http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/362-An-almost-idiots-guide-to-install-PostgreSQL-9.5,-PostGIS-2.2-and-pgRouting-2.1.0-with-Yum.html and it works, I've tried to execute manually all the steps and now I'd like to try to automate them. This guide says " .... 
Installing postgres creates a user account called postgres. If you want to change the password to something you know do this:
sudo passwd postgres
You'll be prompted for a new password. .... ". So I think that the user is a system user, May I avoid to define a password for the postgres user? .....